# Mysql row position(rank)

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table "course_marks" which has 3 fields 
            studentID, courseID, mark. 
 I want to get the rank of a particular studentID for a particular courseID on the basis of mark(order by mark desc). The query should return a single row that indicates the rank. Ignore the same mark condition. How can I get the result in a single mysql query ?

Comment: How same marks affect the rank position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should decide how identical marks will be treated when calculating the rank. This query for marks: 5,5,4 will calculate the rank of students with mark 4 as 3rd rank:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(r.mark)+1 as rank
FROM
    course_marks cm
LEFT JOIN
    course_marks r ON r.courseID = cm.courseID AND r.mark > cm.mark
WHERE 
    cm.studentID = %STUDENT_ID% AND
    cm.courseID = %COURSE_ID%
```

This query for marks: 5,5,4 will calculate the rank of students with mark 4 as 2nd:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.mark)+1 as rank
FROM
    course_marks cm
LEFT JOIN
    course_marks r ON r.courseID = cm.courseID AND r.mark > cm.mark
WHERE 
    cm.studentID = %STUDENT_ID% AND
    cm.courseID = %COURSE_ID%
```

Comment: Thank You Przemysław Jan Wróbel. Your query gave the correct result.